# No display at all tests, but shows continuity

Tags: multimeter, display, buzzer

My multimeter buzzer is ok and  sounds when continuity is checked. However, no display on the LCD. Also, no numbers are showing in every tests voltage, resistance, etc.

I have replaced the battery and checked for any damages on the board. No signs of it and have cleaned everything.

How to check if power is supplied to the main IC chips?

Comment: What meter?  (Brand and model.)  Do you have a schematic diagram for it?  Do you have a second meter you can use to make measurements on the broken one?

Comment: To be honest, it sounds more like  a problem with the display than with power to the  ICs.

Comment: Unity brand. And model is dt830d

Answer (score 2):

830 type multimeters are known to be of low quality. Harbor Freight used to give then out for free. It is probably not worth your time to troubleshoot. Most likely, either the LCD or the Main IC is trashed. In either case, it is not worth fixing even if parts are available. Get another one if that is all you can afford or upgrade to a better meter.